# after npm run dev, cannot close terminal

Tags: npm, xampp, vite, npm-run

before month, new project installation + Jetstream, after run `npm install && npm run dev` command, I close Terminal and all was working through **xampp**. but now, after `npm run dev` it writes:

> dev
>
> vite
>
> vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:
>
> Local: http://localhost:3000/
>
> Network: use `--host` to expose
>
> ready in 270ms.
>
> Laravel v9.19.0
>
> APP_URL: http://localhost

and if I close terminal, I can't do login or register anymore : (

```
Vite manifest not found at:
```

*can someone help ?*

Comment: Vite manifest not found at ->It's because of your old nodejs version. Update nodejs. Close it by ctrl+c.

Comment: did it, but not helps : (